# Sort list of class objects two ways?

Tags: apex

I want to sort a list of objects of a class by 2 ways.
I am able to do custom sort by overwriting the compareTo method.

But I have two lists and I want to sort them differently.

Can I still accomplish this by calling the list.sort() method?

```
global class myClass implements Comparable{

    public integer Total{get;set;}
    public integer numOfDays{get;set;}

    global Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
        myClass compareToEmp = (myClass)compareTo;
        if (Total == myClass.Total) return 0;
        if (Total > myClass.Total) return 1;
        return -1;        
    }
}
```

In the above example, how can I also be able to sort by "numOfDays"?

**//UPDATE:**

I actually wanted to sort list by single property.

But use different properties to sort different lists.

I ended up adding a new field to my class for sorting purpose.

```
global class myClass implements Comparable{

    public integer Total{get;set;}
    public integer numOfDays{get;set;}
    public boolean isA {get;set;}

    global Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
        myClass compareToEmp = (myClass)compareTo;
        if(isA){

        if (Total == myClass.Total) return 0;
        if (Total > myClass.Total) return 1;
            return -1; }
        else{
             if (Total == myClass.numOfDays) return 0;
        if (Total > myClass.numOfDays) return 1;
            return -1; 
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: so when you call sort() on list A, it gets sorted by total and when you call sort() on list B, you want to sort by numOfDays?  If YES, then introduce a sortKey property that is set before you invoke sort()

Comment: @crop1645 yes, you are right. I might describe my problem ambiguously.  How does the sortKey property work?

Comment: so -- please edit the original post (OP) to clarify your question as @Adrianlarson answer assumes you have a major and minor key sort

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to apply a secondary sort, it seems that should be in your `==` logical branch. It is hard to tell based on your naming what you are going for, because `myClass` is your `object` type, not your `instance` name (which is actually `compareToEmp`).

```
global Integer compareTo(Object obj)
{
    if (obj instanceOf MyClass)
    {
        MyClass compareTo = (MyClass)obj;
        if (compareTo.total > this.total) return -1;
        else if (compareTo.total < this.total) return 1;
        else // compareTo.total == this.total
        {
            if (compareTo.numOfDays > this.numOfDays) return -1;
            else if (compareTo.numOfDays < this.numOfDays) return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If you want to be able to sort by one key *or* the other depending on your needs, you will want to implement some mechanism by which you can retrieve (and toggle) the value to sort by.

```
global class MyClass implements Comparable
{
    global static Boolean sortByTotal = true;

    global Integer total { get; private set; }
    global Integer dayCount { get; private set; }

    global Integer compareTo(Object obj)
    {
        if (obj instanceOf MyClass)
        {
            MyClass that = (MyClass)obj;
            return this.getSortValue() - that.getSortValue();
            // if you prefer, you can still compare the values and return 1 or -1
            // it may also be worth adding some null checks
        }
        return 0;
    }
    Integer getSortValue()
    {
        return (sortByTotal) ? total : dayCount;
    }
}
```