# How do I transform SOQL result and output to PageBlockTable?

Tags: visualforce, soql, wrapper-class

I am attempting to transform data returned by a SOQL query that references multiple objects. Below is a graphical representation of the SOQL output, and the desired appearance of that data in a `PageBlockTable` element.

**SOQL Result:**

```
  Year  | ID |   Type   |  Value
-----------------------------------
  2016    10   Original     800
  2016    10   Proposed     750
  2016    10   Final        775
  2015    10   Original     600
  2015    10   Proposed     500
  2015    10   Final        520
  2014    10   Original     600
  2014    10   Proposed     500
  2014    10   Final        510
```

**Desired representation:**

```
  Year  | ID | Original | Proposed |  Final
---------------------------------------------
  2016    10     800        750        775
  2015    10     600        500        520
  2014    10     600        500        510
```

**Visualforce Page:**

```
<apex:page controller="SummaryController">
   <apex:pageBlock title="Value Summary">
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Summary}" var="item">
         <apex:column value="{!item.Year__r.Name}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!item.Summary_Record_Type__c}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!item.Year__r.ID_Number__r.Name}"/>
         <apex:column value="{!item.Val_Summary__r.Value__c}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
   </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

**Apex Class:**

```
public class SummaryController {

    public Id accId {get; set;}
    public List<Summary_Record__c> Summary {get; set;}

    public SummaryController() {
        accId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().Get('id');
        Summary = [SELECT Id, Name, Year__r.Name, Summary_Record_Type__c, Year__r.ID_Number__r.Name, Year__r.Site__r.Name, Val_Summary__r.Name, Val_Summary__r.Value__c
                FROM Summary_Record__c 
                WHERE Year__r.Site__r.Id = :accId 
                ORDER BY Year__r.Name DESC];
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the code?

Comment: Do you have a class and a visualforce page already created? You can assign the query result to a collection ( list, map. set) and build your pageblocktable based on the collection. Take a look at this post : https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000Ag9bIAC

Comment: Paste related code so that someone can help.

Comment: Are you trying to display this data for one `ID` value, or can there be multiple?

Comment: @AdrianLarson there may be multiple, but only in very rare circumstances. I am trying to focus on solving the core problem, then I will worry about different iterations. I will post code shortly.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is to use a wrapper class. You probably need to map by `Year` to de-duplicate the rows, and also implement `Comparable` so you can sort afterword. I will assume here that you have one unique `ID` value, and you can explore how to add that complexity in as a learning experience.

Your wrapper should look like:

```
public class SummaryWrapper implements Comparable
{
    public Integer year { get; private set; }
    public String id { get; private set; }
    public String originalValue { get; private set; }
    public String proposedValue { get; private set; }
    public String finalValue { get; private set; }
    // final is a reserved keyword

    public Integer compareTo(Object instance)
    {
        Comparable that = (Comparable)instance;
        if (this.year == null) return 1;
        if (that.year == null) return -1;
        return that.year - this.year;

        // above is descending order, nulls last

        // to put nulls first, swap 1 and -1

        // to use ascending order, swap that and this
        // (on the final line)
    }
}
```

Then you can loop through your query results and create these wrappers. Something like:

```
Map<Integer, SummaryWrapper> wrappers = new Map<Integer, SummaryWrapper>();
for (Summary__c record : [/*query*/])
{
    Integer year = (Integer)record.Year__c;
    if (!wrappers.containsKey(year))
        wrappers.put(year, new SummaryWrapper());
    SummaryWrapper wrapper = wrappers.get(year);
    wrapper.year = year;
    wrappers.id = record.Year__r.ID_Number__r.Name;
    if (record.Summary_Record_Type__c == 'Original')
        wrapper.originalValue = record.Val_Summary__r.Value__c;
    if (record.Summary_Record_Type__c == 'Proposed')
        wrapper.proposedValue = record.Val_Summary__r.Value__c;
    if (record.Summary_Record_Type__c == 'Final')
        wrapper.finalValue = record.Val_Summary__r.Value__c;
}
summaries = wrappers.values().clone();
summaries.sort();
```

Make sure you set a property on your controller:

```
public List<SummaryWrapper> summaries { get; private set; }
```

For information on a two key sort, see: [Sort list of class objects two ways?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/91866/sort-list-of-class-objects-two-ways/91867#91867)

For more information on how to map by complex keys, see: [How to implement hashCode cleanly?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4569/how-to-implement-hashcode-cleanly)

As for the markup to display this data, it should be pretty simple to figure out yourself. :) You'll need to set the `headerValue` attribute on each `<apex:column>`.

Comment: Thank you very much Adrian! This looks very helpful. I have a quick question about how you implemented the compareTo method. I noted that the example in the [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm) compares against the parent class. Why is it that you cast the object to Comparable instead of SummaryWrapper?